# numpy randint generation as a string

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to learn TensorFLow and NumPY, however, I appear to be having an issue with NumPY creating strings instead of an int.

here are the lines of code where the error occurs:

```
    data = int(np.random.randint(1000, size="10000"))

    x = tf.constant(data, name="x")
```

and the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/TesorLearn/Main.py", line 4, in <module>
      data = int(np.random.randint(1000, size="10000"))
    File "mtrand.pyx", line 995, in mtrand.RandomState.randint
    File "mtrand.pyx", line 996, in mtrand.RandomState.randint
    File "randint_helpers.pxi", line 202, in mtrand._rand_int32
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**strong text**
```

so is there a method of it generating the array as INT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a bit of messing around i figured it out as NumPY works like so:

```
np.random.randint(low,high.size,dataType)
```

so the line of code to solve my problem is:

```
data = np.random.randint(0,1000,10000,int)
```

Comment: Size can also be [a tuple](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) to shape your numpy array.